# Pass a parameter to Geb's static at() while in a Spock Specification

Tags: webdriver, spock, geb

Is it possible for me to pass a parameter to “at()” so I can use a parameter in a module?  Here is my scenario:

Module for a page that has some common detail about a product (ProductModule, this has a content title which I would like to paramertize).  I have a Page that uses that module but I would like the “at()” to have the product title passed to it during the tests.  Is this possible?

My use would be (in psudo-code)

```
...
...
when:
go ProductPage

then:
at ProductPage(title:”Product title goes here”) // this is the parameter I want to pass down to the “at” since the check is a content segment in the Module

and:
…
…
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a static field on the ProductPage:

ProductPage.title = "the title"

where the at definition would then use the ProductPage.title field

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "no." And I haven't found an alternative way to achieve this. Since you asked the question a few months ago, perhaps you have?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the creators of the library are hesitant to create a feature like.  The feature (individual test methods) should be responsible for the checking.  I still would like to see something related to this so I can keep a simple set of "Page" objects